# Simple ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a button in the fist div that triggers the second div to show if clicked. It is simple and straight forward. But the second div does not show.

HTML

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    Blah
    <button ng-click = "toggleDetail()" class = "btn btn-default"> <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span> </button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show = "showDetail">
    clicked button
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.showDetail = false;

$scope.toggleDetail = function() {
    $scope.showDetail = !$scope.showDetail;
};
```

PS. I followed example from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_events

Comment: Where do you specify the path to AngularJS? Where do you specify the ng-app? Where do you specify the ng-controller? Please add the complete html document (it can't be that big?)

Comment: Add an ng-controller attribute to the tag so angular knows which controller to use and inject the scope properly.

Comment: Please post a url to a Plunkr...
The code you have provided is accurate and it should work.. something else is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Everyone is right, I messed up the scopes by accidentally putting a </div> in my code

Comment: The problem of copy-pasting code!? :P

Comment: @chrisv nope, the problem of staying up all night to code

Comment: The power of coffee! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything seems to be Ok in your example. If you just do such simple stuff you don't have to use a controller function, you can do everything in html

```
<div ng-init="showDetail=false" class="alert alert-danger">
    Blah
    <button ng-click = "showDetail = !showDetail" class = "btn btn-default"> <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span> </button>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning"  ng-show = "showDetail">
    clicked button
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and sweet, but this is not a good habit to get into because it will catch you out when you find yourself in a child scope (like ng-repeat)

Comment: I think this user is trying to learn Angular, and this isn't actually explaining anything...?

Comment: @randomsock inside ng-repeat loop you can do the same because of `$index`. Like `ng-init="showDetail_$index = false"`.

Comment: @chrisv at least I show a workable solution. And it isn`t possible to say what went wrong based on the showed code.